# Kitty terminal topbar looks weird. How to make it look normal again?

Tags: command-line, kitty-terminal

My Kitty terminal for no absolute reason changed its topbar. Now it looks like this:

[image: Kitty terminal with weird topbar]

Comment: Can you rephrase your post as a question

Answer (score 1):

Setting `hide_window_decorations` to `yes` in the kitty config solved this for me.